# How to access CSS of locally installed NPM package

Tags: css, angular, npm

I have download and installed NPM package,but i am not able to access css of installed package.
I am using [this](https://designsystem.ihsmarkit.com/library/quick-start) package.can anyone help me out ? as per the documentation i need to add following css files.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/grid.css" /><!-- Opt-in Default Grid -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap4-scoped.css" /><!-- Optional scoped version of Bootstrap 4 -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles-nw.css" /><!-- Core Styles (which already includes all needed Bootstrap 3 styles) -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap4-override.css" /><!-- Optional Bootstrap 4 Overrides -->
```

I have added in index.html in angular project:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="cpl-scope">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>IhsPoc</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/grid.css" /><!-- Opt-in Default Grid -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap4-scoped.css" /><!-- Optional scoped version of Bootstrap 4 -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles-nw.css" /><!-- Core Styles (which already includes all needed Bootstrap 3 styles) -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap4-override.css" /><!-- Optional Bootstrap 4 Overrides -->
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "ihs-poc",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    "csspatternlibrary3": "file:node_modules/csspatternlibrary3@3.0.3",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.20",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.20",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.14",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
}
```

npm package entry is available but not able to access css

```
"csspatternlibrary3": "file:node_modules/csspatternlibrary3@3.0.3"
```

Comment: Read: [Angular Tutorial - Adding a library to the runtime global scope](https://angular.io/guide/using-libraries#adding-a-library-to-the-runtime-global-scope)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to add it to `angular.json` file. Add path to file into `"styles": []`

for example: `"styles": ["node_modules/foo/bar.css"]`